# Instrumental tests - null pointer exception on setContentView()

Tags: android, testing, nullpointerexception, android-espresso

I have an instrumental test located at `app/androidTest/java/myapp`. I have one simple test method in there:

```
public class LoginActivityTest {

    private static final String EMAIL = "admin@gmail.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "admin";

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<LoginActivity> loginActivity = new IntentsTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void LoginWithProperCredentials() {
        onView(withId(R.id.email_textView))
                .perform(typeText(EMAIL));
        onView(withId(R.id.password_login))
                .perform(typeText(PASSWORD));
        onView(withId(R.id.email_sign_in_button))
                .perform(click());

        intended(allOf(
                hasExtra(GeneralConstants.AUTHENTICATED, true),
                hasExtra(GeneralConstants.TOKEN, isA(String.class)),
                toPackage("myapp")));
    }
}
```

I have upgraded Android Support Repository, added neccessary `androidTestCompile` dependencies as well as default testInstrumentationRunner (`"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`) and I've chosen `Android Instrumentation Tests` as Build Variant. Yet, attempting to launch the test gives me `ResourceNotFoundException`. I've figured out, that it's the `setContentView()` method in `onCreate(Bundle bundle)` that throws this Exception.

I'm being struggling with this for a while now. What could be the reason for it?

**EDIT:**

I've checked that in `myapp.test.R` there is a missing field that is causing `ResourceNotFoundException`. This field is also in `myapp.R`, but it has different value assosiated to it (0x7f040015 and 0x7f030015 in `test.R`-this one is missing). I've tried to explicitly import:

```
import pl.kawowydzienniczek.kawowydzienniczek.test.R;
```

But then trying to write:

```
onView(withId(R.id.email_textView))
                .perform(typeText(EMAIL));
```

gives me the error saying that `email_textView` cannot be resolved.
How should it be done?

**EDIT2:**

I've noticed that commenting out the following dependency

`androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'`

makes it work. For now it should be okay, but why is that and how to make espresso work without throwing that library out?

Comment: just curious, but do you have multiple resource files for that activity?

Comment: what do you mean by multiple resources? I have one `res` folder and one `layout` folder in it.

Comment: Does that activity have multiple layouts? For example layout and layout-land. But from your last response it doesn't sound like it. I've had issues where i have multiple layouts with differing view elements which caused a similar issue that you described.

Comment: I've noticed that my `LoginActivityTest` uses `myapp.R` package instead of 'myapp.test.R`. Trying to import that explicitly fails, because then I cannot get the views defined in my xml file.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it should be okay for your test class to use import myapp.R. can you check to see if your LoginActivityTest class file has the same package as LoginActivity?

Answer (score 0):

According to

> For now it should be okay, but why is that and how to make espresso
>   work without throwing that library out?

here's my `build.gradle` config:

```
dependencies {
    ext.JUNIT_VERSION = '4.12'
    ext.SUPPORT_VERSION = '24.1.1'
    ext.ESPRESSO_VERSION = '2.2.2'

    compile fileTree(dir: ulibs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile "junit:junit:$JUNIT_VERSION"
    testCompile("org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0") {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_VERSION"

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    /**
     * AccessibilityChecks
     * CountingIdlingResource
     * DrawerActions
     * DrawerMatchers
     * PickerActions (Time and Date picker)
     * RecyclerViewActions
     */
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    compile "junit:junit:${JUNIT_VERSION}"
}
```

Try to exclude the same groups modules and groups as I've already done.

Check: https://github.com/piotrek1543/LocalWeather/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Hope it will help